# Highchart legend pagination on iphone

Tags: iphone, highcharts, pagination, legend

I have used **highcharts** in my **iphone** application, Everything works great except one is that when I click on pagination arrows of legend in highchart, it skips one page and goes to next page.

Say I have 4 pages, so if I am on **1st page right now** and click to view another page then it **jumps to 3rd page**. After clicking **next** for 3rd page I **go to 4th page** and when I click on **prev** it skips 3rd page and **jumps to 2nd page**. And very important to take note is, its happening on **iphone only not browser**.

I am surprised to see this and unable to identify why this behaviour is there with pagination...

following is my code for creating highchart

```
var defaultBarChart = {
                options: {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        alignTicks:false,
                        //height: 250,
                        width: Constants.analyticChartWidth
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: ''+$filter('translate')('values')
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                         enabled: false,
                         style: {
                                width: 200,
                                padding: 10,
                                lineHeight: "normal"
                            },
                        useHTML:true                    
                     },
                    legend: {
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 0,    
                        itemStyle: {
                            width: deviceWidth,
                            'color':'#434f5a',
                            'font-size':'12px'
                        },
                    maxHeight: 105,
                    navigation: {
                        activeColor: '#3E576F',
                        animation: true,
                        arrowSize: 18,
                        inactiveColor: '#CCC'
                    }
                    },
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        ''
                    ],
                    crosshair: true
                },
                tooltip: {
                     /* style: {
                         width: 100
                     }*/
                     enabled: false
                 },
               /* tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                         width: 100
                     }
                },*/
                series: [{
                    name: '',
                    data: [0],
                    showInLegend: false
                }],

                loading: false,
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                }
       };
```

I want to ask, if problem anywhere else other than navigation can affect on it?

Please.. help me to get out of this...!!

Comment: As I remember, there was similar issue when using fast-click library (or something similar) which doubles click events. Could you check that? See similar issue [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2452).

Comment: I got the root cause of problem, there is **onclick** event associated with up and down arrows in **highcharts.js**,  that event is fired 2 times for ios device. So  click on next skips one page and go to next.

Comment: Yes, of course, that's how it works ;) But do you see the same error on the official demo pages? You said it works in browser, so I assume you have some library which calls event twice.

Comment: I am only using **highcharts.js**, **highcharts-ng.js** and **highcharts-more.js** .... I didn't found any kind of error relating to mine one...

Comment: I think it's `highcharts-ng` plugin. See [bug report](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/456). And your "only using" should also mention angular, don't you think? ;)

Comment: ohh.... excuse me please...!! ok i'll check bug report...!! and let you know further...

Comment: hi @pawel... this question is asked by my friend only...!!

Comment: Maybe you should ping creator of this wrapper about status of this bug?

Comment: Ya, I mailed them, thanks for your assistance..!!

Comment: This is open issue of highchart, still in desktop http://jsfiddle.net/viethien/2c4owgj5/